# How to add a $ sign in front of the amounts?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code I show hereunder has got some if statements which make different variables which all involve money. When I run the code I can select how many of any drink and if it is takeaway or not. 
IF it iss takeaway it adds 5% to the cost and if there are more than 3 drinks it takes 10% off the invoice.

Could anyone help me add a `+$` for the takeaway on the output area of gui and a `-$` for the discount.

Any help would be appreciated.

If anyone wants to see the entire code, it is visible in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/SJones72413/8d6957a5078d37ea56335a0cb5c1f056)

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1600x8000")
root.title("Cafe au Lait")

tops = tk.Frame(root, width=1600, relief="sunken")
tops.pack(side="top")
f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=700, relief="sunken")
f1.pack(side="left")

latte = tk.DoubleVar()
double_expresso = tk.DoubleVar()
iced = tk.DoubleVar()
cost = tk.DoubleVar()
cappacuino = tk.DoubleVar()
expresso = tk.DoubleVar()
flat_white = tk.DoubleVar()
total = tk.DoubleVar()
takeaway_var = tk.StringVar()
rand = tk.IntVar()
discount = tk.DoubleVar()
takeaway = tk.DoubleVar()

def ref(even=None):
    x=random.randint(10000,99999)
    randomRef=str(x)
    rand.set(randomRef)

    global total, cost
    if latte.get() == "":
        col = 0
    else:
        col = latte.get() 
    if iced.get() == "":
        coi = 0
    else:
       coi = iced.get()
    if flat_white.get() == "":
        cofw = 0
    else:
        cofw = flat_white.get()
    if double_expresso.get() == "":
        code = 0
    else:
        code = double_expresso.get()
    if cappacuino.get() == "":
        coc = 0
    else:
        coc = cappacuino.get()
    if expresso.get() == "":
        coe = 0
    else:
        coe = expresso.get()

    costoflatte = col * 3.5
    costoficed = coi * 2.5
    costofflat_white = cofw * 3.75
    costofdouble_expresso = code * 4.25
    costofcappacuino = coc * 3.75
    costofexpresso = coe * 3

    total.set('{}'.format(cost.get() + costoflatte + costoficed + costofflat_white + costofdouble_expresso + costofcappacuino + costofexpresso))
    cost.set('{}'.format(cost.get() + costoflatte + costoficed + costofflat_white + costofdouble_expresso + costofcappacuino + costofexpresso))

    if txt_takeaway.get() in ['Yes', 'yes', 'y', 'Y']:
        w = total.get()
        takeaway.set(w * 0.05)

    if txt_takeaway.get() in ['Yes', 'yes', 'y', 'Y']:
        x = total.get()
        total.set((x * 0.05) + x)

    if (coc + col + coi + cofw + code + coe) >=3:
        z = total.get()
        discount.set(z * 0.1)

    if (coc + col + coi + cofw + code + coe) >=3:
        y = total.get()
        total.set(y * 0.9)
```

The code above sets it all up so that the code below outputs corrdctly. It is needed to run. The first 2 buttons below are the ones that need the +$ and -$ added to.

```
lbl_takeaway= tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Takeaway",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=2, column=2)
txt_takeaway=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=takeaway,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_takeaway.grid(row=2,column=3)

lbl_discount= tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Discount",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=3, column=2)
txt_discount=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=discount,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_discount.grid(row=3,column=3)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Order Number",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=2)
txt_order=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=rand,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_order.grid(row=0,column=3)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Takeaway", bd=16, anchor="w").grid(row=6, column=0)
txt_takeaway = tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=takeaway_var, bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg="powder blue", justify='right')
txt_takeaway.grid(row=6, column=1)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Cost of Order", bd=16, anchor="w").grid(row=1, column=2)
txt_cost = tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'), textvariable=cost,bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg="powder blue", justify='right')
txt_cost.grid(row=1, column=3)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Total Cost", bd=16, anchor="w").grid(row=5, column=2)
txt_totalcost = tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'), textvariable=total, bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg="powder blue", justify='right')
txt_totalcost.grid(row=5, column=3)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Latte",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=1, column=0)
txt_latte=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=latte,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_latte.grid(row=1,column=1)

btnTotal=tk.Button(f1,padx=16,pady=8,bd=16,fg="black",font=('arial',16,'bold'),width=10,text="Total",bg="powder blue",command=ref).grid(row=7,column=1)

root.bind("<Return>", ref)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your edit made it even less of a good example What @j_4321 was referring to was a minimal amount of code we can paste and run, to see what you have, preferably with a comment on where you want the change. `ref` for example, seems completely irrelevant, put something short there to just set some numbers.

Comment: Where exactly would you like to add the `$` to? Could you simply add a label on the right of the entries containing the prices?

Comment: So in the discount entry box for example where it displayed 10% of the total price I would like it to have a -$ in front of it so that if people are looking at it they know it is being subtracted. Currently it still subtracts but it just displays the number alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a default value in the entry field; here is a little example that subclasses `tk.Entry`, that you can reuse in your own project:

```
import tkinter as tk

class EntryBoxWithNegativeDollarSign(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(self.master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.default = '-$'
        self.insert(0, self.default)
        self.pack()

    def set_default(self):
        self.delete('0',tk.END)
        self.insert(0, self.default)

    def get(self):
        value = - float(super().get()[2:])
        self.set_default()
        print(value)

        return value

root = tk.Tk()
app = tk.Frame(root)
app.pack()
entry = EntryBoxWithNegativeDollarSign(app)
tk.Button(app, text='get value', command=entry.get).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Will this work with my code where I have the entry box display a variable that always changes? Will it automatically go in front of any number that appears? Thanks for taking the time to do this also.

Comment: No idea about your code, I don't think anybody wants to read it anyway! You'll have to try, but this will work in lieu of a `tkEntry`, in any program that runs.